# Getting the text from dropdown list and Insert it into input text using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

How can i get the text from the dropdown list and insert it into input text using jquery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
        Item 0:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-1-item">
        Item 1:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-1-item" name="lines-1-item" title="">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-1-label" type="text" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-2-item">
        Item 2:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-2-item" name="lines-2-item" title="">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-2-label" type="text" />
<script>
    var label1 = document.getElementById('id_lines-0-item');
    var strlabel1 = label1.options[label1.selectedIndex].text;
    $('input:text').val(strlabel1);
</script>
```

I have tried this above code but it is not working and please forgive me if this a stupid question as i am learning jquery.

I have updated my question. I need to get the text from dropdown list with `id="id_lines-0-item"` and set the value to input text with `id="id_lines-0-label"` and respectively getting the value from dropdown list with `id="id_lines-1-item"` and set the value to input text with `id="id_lines-1-label"` and so on. Can this be done using DRY(Don't repeat yourself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate a `onchange()` function in your `select` dropdown and use `selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text` to get the selected option's text using JavaScript. Since, you have `id` for the `text` input it is always a better to use the `id` selector. In your case `$('#id_lines-0-label')`. Also, since you have separate text input for separate dropdown and you do not want to repeat the code for all three dropdowns, it is better to use the number value from the `id` of the dropdown. Use this value and concatenate to get the `id` of the `input` box.

```js
function onchangeFn(selection) {
    var id= $(selection).attr('id');
    var num = id.match(/\d+/)[0];
    var strlabel1 = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text;
    $('#id_lines-'+num+'-label').val(strlabel1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
        Item 0:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="" onchange= 'onchangeFn(this)'>
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-1-item">
        Item 1:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-1-item" name="lines-1-item" title="" onchange = 'onchangeFn(this)'>
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-1-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-1-label" type="text" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-2-item">
        Item 2:
    </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-2-item" name="lines-2-item" title="" onchange = 'onchangeFn(this)'>
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-2-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-2-label" type="text" />
```

Comment: @MikePinkman let me know if this is exactly what you expect to be or not

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with the on change event. Here I have use an on change event for select box. When you make changes to select box the function attached with event will trigger. And also if you want the result on page load , call the same function function at the time of page load like I did using `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
   updateValue($(this));
});

function updateValue(ele){   
    ele.closest('.form-group').find('input').val($("option:selected", ele).text());
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    updateValue($('#id_lines-0-item'));   
    updateValue($('#id_lines-1-item'));
    updateValue($('#id_lines-2-item'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
    Item:
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
  <input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
    Item:
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-1-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
  <input id="id_lines-1-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-1-label" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-1-item">
    Item:
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-2-item" name="lines-2-item" title="">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
  <input id="id_lines-2-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-2-label" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update on select change

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
        Item:
      </label>
      <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="2">Baja</option>
        <option value="3">Fish</option>
        <option value="4">Tacos</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
    <script>

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var strlabel1 =$('#id_lines-0-item option:selected').text();
  $('input:text').val(strlabel1);
})
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfect !!

Just call some event on selection of dropdownlist like this

here is my edited answer.
pass this(id) & index as a parameter and on the base of index set text to appropriate text field id.

Hope this will helpful for you!!!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
    Item:
  </label>
  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="" onchange="setTest(this,0)">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />

  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-1-item" name="lines-1-item" title="" onchange="setTest(this,1)">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-1-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />

  <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-2-item" name="lines-2-item" title="" onchange="setTest(this,2)">
    <option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="2">Baja</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
    <option value="4">Tacos</option>
  </select>
</div>
<input id="id_lines-2-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
<script>
  function setTest(el,index){
   var label1 = $(el).val();
   var strlabel1 = label1.options[label1.selectedIndex].text;
    if(index == 0)     
      $('#id_lines-0-label').val(strlabel1);
    else if(index == 1)
      $('#id_lines-1-label').val(strlabel1);
    else if(index == 2)
      $('#id_lines-2-label').val(strlabel1);

   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
            Item:
          </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
            <option value="">---------</option>
            <option value="2">Baja</option>
            <option value="3">Fish</option>
            <option value="4">Tacos</option>
          </select>

<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
            Item:
          </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
            <option value="">---------</option>
            <option value="2">Baja</option>
            <option value="3">Fish</option>
            <option value="4">Tacos</option>
          </select>

<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_lines-0-item">
            Item:
          </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="id_lines-0-item" name="lines-0-item" title="">
            <option value="">---------</option>
            <option value="2">Baja</option>
            <option value="3">Fish</option>
            <option value="4">Tacos</option>
          </select>

<input id="id_lines-0-label" maxlength="255" name="lines-0-label" type="text" />
        </div>
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

$('select option').click(function(){

$(this).closest('.form-group').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
});
    </script>
```